# Using grid in globe map indicator of ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts, grids-graticules, globe

I'm trying to reproduce a map indicator such as:

[image]

But in ArcGIS Pro, grids are only available to 2D maps. So far I've got this:

[image]

Is there a way to add a grid in 3D maps without adding an extra layer (such a shapefile with CRS's grid net) or a way to visualize 2D maps as a globe?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to use a modified Vertical Perspective (Sphere) CRS in a 2D map.

Modifying Longitude and Latitude of Center you can rotate the sphere:

[image]

[image]

Grids can be added easily.